# ARKit: Change light intensity and temperature on the scene

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, light

So, I'm playing with ARKit and now I want to manually change light intensity and temperature using UISlider (for example I want to make the whole scene dark and cold). I found this 2 properties in documentation:
`ambientColorTemperature: CGFloat { get }` and `ambientIntensity: CGFloat { get }`.

Apple says I can pass this values directly to **temperature** and **intensity** properties of a SceneKit ambient light. So that's what I've done:

```
for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes {
     node.light?.intensity = CGFloat(slider.value)
}
```

And so on with temperature. But nothing happened.

Any help would be very helpful.

I'm using Xcode 9.1, iOS 11.1.1

Comment: Are there any nodes with attached `SCNLight` objects in the scene? Basic Swift: if `node.light` is nil, none of the code after the question mark runs.

Comment: Yes, in ViewDidAppear() I add SCNLight to scene's rootNode. But it seems to me that I'm looking in the wrong direction.